# How to reduce this expression?

Tags: derivatives

We first define the following polynomial:

$$y(x)=\prod_{j=1}^{n}(x-x_j)$$

Then I want to compute $-\frac{y''(x)}{2y'(x)}$, So I've got so far

$$y'(x)=\sum_{k=2}^{n} \prod_{j=k}^{n}(x-x_j)$$

I got that because I realized, doing the math, that each time we are avoiding the first, second, third, etc. term. Therefore doing the same idea, the second derivative is

$$y''(x)=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\sum_{r=3}^{n} \prod_{j=r}^{n}(x-x_j)$$

So my question is, What can be done to have a nice expression for $-\frac{y''(x)}{2y'(x)}$ to get that

$$\frac{y''(x)}{2y'(x)}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(x-x_j)}?$$

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Take logs first and then differentiate twice.

So, $$\frac{y'}{y}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(x-x_j)}$$
then, $$\frac{yy''-y'y'}{y^2}=-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(x-x_j)^2}$$

Rearrange.

So you get $$-\frac{y''}{2y}=\frac 12\left[\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(x-x_j)^2}-\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x-x_j}\right)^2\right]$$

And finally, $$-\frac{y''}{2y'}=\frac 12\left[\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(x-x_j)}\right]^{-1}\left[\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(x-x_j)^2}-\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x-x_j}\right)^2\right]$$

Comment: Right, but what do you mean by rearrange? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I have added some lines

Comment: How did you get the first part?

Comment: I took logs first, then differentiated

Comment: Ok, but I think that the expression I am looking is that one but it should emerge at the end of the process, How can you explain that?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean. Please rephrase your question

Comment: How did you get $y'$ into the denominator?

Comment: No, I suppose to get the first expression $y'/y$ for $y''/y'$, I mean, I think the last expression is incorrect

Comment: I forgot to type in the last step sorry!

Comment: So your expression is incorrect right ?

Comment: I mean, I should get that the result for $y''/y'$ is in fact the one that you get for $y'/y$ so that is why I am saying that something is wrong :)

Comment: I have edited my post ;)

Comment: Then, what do you think?

Comment: I've edited my post :)